# Laravel undefined function env

Tags: laravel

I have cloned a Laravel 6 project. I have an error everywhere `env()` function is called in config files.

I'm using PHP 7.3

PS: `composer install` worked fine.

Comment: try php artisan config:clear

Comment: Nothing has changed. Plus, I have noticed it's more than just `env()` function that is not working. IT seems like all Laravel helpers are not working. Example `storage_path()`, `resource_path()`, etc...

Comment: also try giving vendor folder permission etc,,

Comment: Remove the `vendor` directory and do a fresh `composer install`.

Answer (score -3):

The solution to my problem was to disable `PHP Intelephense` and then, restart Visual Studio code.